# Create folds from given elements of matrix

Tags: r, vector, r-caret, cross-validation

I have a numeric vector of certain numbers:

```
str(vector)
 int [1:15463] 389 1732 1737 2127 2205 3163 5166 5601 5981 6860 ...
```

and I want to create `n` folds containing those numbers above.

When I try that with function `createFolds` from `caret` package

```
flds <- createFolds(vector,10)
```

I get only numbers in range of 1 to `length(vector)`.

How can I create folds containing only values from that vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
lapply(flds, function(x) vector[x])
```